# What's the best way to get a UITableViewController to refresh its tableview upon rotation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

What's the best way to get a UITableViewController to refresh its tableview upon rotation? I'm surprised that the UITableViewController doesn't take care of this automatically.

Comment: the UITableViewController calls the layoutSubview Method from the visible Cell if the Device Rotates. Have you implement the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation ?

Comment: Use the `reloadData` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];    
}
```